# Is it usually better to design multithreaded programs were each thread does a series of tasks or many groups of threads doing 1 task each?

Tags: multithreading

Say program 1 has N threads where each thread does task A, task B, task C in sequence.

Program 2 has 3 thread pools of N threads each where each pool does one task only and after each task is done it is passed to threads in the other pool using thread safe queues/objects.

Which one is usually better, design wise and/or performance wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty complicated question.

In terms of *throughput*, both approaches usually perform about the same when the system is under load.  If you want to maximize throughput, you just have to make sure all your cores are busy doing work that needs doing, and that works just as well with either design.

In terms of *latency* -- wall clock time required for each ABC sequence -- using 1 thread for the whole sequence can sometimes perform better. When the 1 thread is done its A, it will almost always start doing B right away.  If it handed B off to another thread pool, then there would usually be some indeterminate delay before some thread in the B pool picked it up and started working on it.  Again this is only an issue when the system is under stress... but if it's not under stress then it doesn't matter.

In terms of *design*, there are trade-offs.  Option 1 is pretty easy to get right.  If you spend the same resources (same total number of threads), then doing it the easy way will perform well for many kinds of jobs.

Option 2 (multiple pools) is a lot more work to get right, since you have to control how long each queue gets.  If there are already lots of things waiting for B, then you don't want to pick up any more As yet, because you should use those cores for Bs to keep latency down, etc.  For some kinds of jobs, though, this control is useful.  If all of the Bs contend for a common I/O resource, for example, then it might not make sense to have a whole bunch of threads doing B anyway, since all but one or two will be blocked at all times.  In this kind of scenario, Option 2 will have fewer thread stacks hanging around in memory doing nothing, fewer threads contending for scarce resources (contention costs cycles), etc.

As a general rule, I would use option 1 for most purposes.  Option 2 is really only useful when you want sophisticated control over scheduling.

But note:  these options are not mutually exclusive.  Even in option 2, each "task" breaks down into smaller tasks, so what we're really talking about is when it's appropriate to hand something off to another thread pool.  You do that when you need different numbers of threads performing each task, and that usually happens when there are some tasks that would cause too many threads to fight with each other for resources or hang around blocking.